# web templates for iphone/ipad/ipod website (as required by the app store)

Tags: iphone, ipad, web, app-store

I'm interested in any free (or paid) web templates for iphone/ipad/ipod websites (as required by the app store).
Note I *do not* mean web templates for web applications (in general), or even  templates for iPhone/iPad/iPod web applications.
I mean the promotional websites (advertising iPhone/iPad/iPod apps) that are required by the app store.
So far I've only found [this](http://www.appstemplates.com/) paid site, and I've also found [this question](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/promotion-techniques/35583-iphone-app-web-template.html), on another developer site.

Note that a response (to the question) had a link to "an art AND a release form on the Apple website. You may not use the image of the iPhone to promote yourself on your website without first signing their application form.", although the link was broken.  Does anybody have an update?

I think the basic requirements are: 
1 - a home page for screen shots, showing off the app
2 - a link to the app store
3 - a FAQ page
4 - a "contact us" or "support" email link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple does not require that your website shows a nice looking template. The page should exist when submitting your app for review and it should show  correct information about your app.

There are several free templates mentioned on iphoneDevSDK, one example is the discussion [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/promotion-techniques/69934-iphone-simulator-your-apps-promotional-website.html). For Wordpress another free one is [here](http://www.rawapps.com/20743/wordpress-theme-for-iphone-app-demo-website-free-download/)

Comment: Thx Olaf.  Those 2 links are the same (I don't think you meant that).  I know it doesn't have to be "nice looking", but it probably helps!  The (single?) useful [link](http://codecanyon.net/item/dragpic-gallery/152440) in that discussion seem to be for a (nice looking) image gallery.  The really cool thing about that is that it has an "iPhone emulator" mode.  See [here](http://development.davoscript.com/dragpic/mobile/).  That is nice, of course, but it isn't a complete template (fulfilling the requirements in the question).

Comment: sorry for the delay in responding, I have now fixed the second link.

Comment: Way cool, thx for that.  That 2nd link is the business! _Exactly_ what the doctor ordered!